# Word Flashing - Word 2010/Windows 10/1909

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, lenovo-laptop, windows-10-v1909

After deploying a firm-wide upgrade to 1903, it has been reported that Word documents start to flash between the document rendered in the Word window to a completely white window and back again, until word is forcibly shut down.

The users are in different parts of the world and are editing different documents.  The documents do seem to be larger documents.  But the documents are not corrupt.  They do not necessarily have more than one or two The users are using Lenovo Yoga (Gen 1) with 8GB of ram.  I've updated the video drivers, disabled hardware graphics acceleration and even gave one user another laptop.  This problem does not happen on firm desktops (Lenovo M93P also with 8GB of ram).

Has anyone seen this?  Thank you.

Comment: Word 2010 (Office 2010) is at or near out of support and not being updated.  On one computer that is giving issues, uninstall Office 2010 completely and try Office 365. Is that causing the same issue?

Comment: Thanks, John.  Unfortunately, we're a large firm and the decision to be on Office 2019 for a while yet isn't mine.  Meanwhile, the users are frustrated and I'm tasked with making the issue go away.

Comment: I have Office 2010 on Windows 7 on a Virtual Machine and it works fine. At this point for Windows 10, you should call Microsoft Support and ask for a Hotfix for it if they will do that (probably will for a large firm).